# counter for relational database entries

Tags: javascript, sql, database, google-maps, relational-database

So I have a database with a bunch of google maps markers and I give users the ability to 'follow' markers. This 'following' information is stored in a separate relational database.

When I load my map and all the associated markers, I would like each marker to display an infowindow (I suspect you all know what this looks like) showing how many people are following the marker. i.e. "23 people are following this marker"

The problem with this would seem to be that if I count the relational database 'followers' while loading the markers, this could be extremely slow, given 1000+ markers. Instead I am thinking of making a marker counter and including it in the original marker database, so I only have to query one database.

Having never made a counter as such (and not finding many specifics on the web), I am wondering if there are any pitfalls I should be aware of? I can see problems arising when users delete their accounts, as I would have to update the counter based on that (not impossible, just kind of a pain), but this could get complicated if I allowed the users to add back their account (as with facebook or something).

Would there be any way for that counter to count the relational database entries periodically so I do no have to update the counter?

from a noob, sincere thanks for any help! It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Databases are pretty good at counting, quickly! The recommended approach is to not store calculated values in your operational database. Try it that way first, measure performance, if it's the slowest part of your app, and there are significant costs associated with that, then start storing counts.
2. If you need to store counts, then consider using caching on your web server, or materialized views and re-generating the counts as required.